# Display HTML of iframe in alert only once iframe HTML has value?

Tags: jquery

Here's what I want to do w/ jquery:

```
var content=$("#iframe01").contents().find("#content").html();

if(/*VARIABLE CONTENT RETURNS NULL*/){check again for its value)

//BUT as soon as it has value, alert('content');
```

---

I DON'T want to use .load or .ready. I think I need to use a loop of some kind… how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.ready` (or `.load`)?  Isn't that how you're *supposed* to do it?  http://jsfiddle.net/PkdaE/

Answer (score 2):

Use `.setInterval()` and continue checking until the value is set. This checks every second ( the `1000` is milliseconds). You can adjust this according to your needs.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/QK5we/

Script:

```js
var timer = window.setInterval( function () {

    var content = $( '#iframe01' ).contents().find( '#branding' ).html();

    if ( content ) {
        window.clearInterval( timer );
        alert( content );
    };

}, 1000 );
```

HTML:

```html
<iframe id="iframe01" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Another option might be to have the iFrame change its own URL param once loaded. Then you just have to check the iFrame src for the presence of, e.g. `loaded=true`